# Vue question-Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get data from post.vue, but it doesn't work. Error message is "Property or method “posts” is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property". Could you help me identify the problem? Thanks in advance.

I have uploaded my code here: https://github.com/Alicezhang821/Problem

Comment: You are referencing `posts` in template of `App.vue`, and your App component doesn't have `posts` defined in either `props` or `data`. You should just be `posts` element here and move the template to `posts` component. Check this: [Vue.js Docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a pull request.

You were trying to use variables in `App.vue` that did not exist. I have moved it to `Post.vue` inside a template section and rendered `<PostExample />` inside of `App.vue`

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you so much!